# Unable to create JAXBContext after writing class with IOException

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I recently had a problem with my code. I am trying to write a class to read my config.properties which is located somewhere in local disk D. However the class bring me problem of unable to create JAXBContext. everything went smooth before so i dont have any idea. Everything run smooth before i make this. i'd suspect that IOException cannot run in web services but i dont know how to fix this problem. Please help me guys i'm stucked.
this is my code:

```
package readConfig;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class readConfig{
public static String getProperties(String key) throws IOException{
Properties property= new Properties();
property.load(new FileInputStream("D:/config.properties"));
return property.getProperty(key);
}
}
```

this is my error code:

```
05-Jul-2018 18:19:24.958 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at java.lang.StackTraceElement
    at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
    at java.lang.Throwable
    at public java.lang.Throwable[] sacredData.jaxws.IOExceptionBean.suppressed
    at sacredData.jaxws.IOExceptionBean

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
... 56 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at java.lang.StackTraceElement
    at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
    at java.lang.Throwable
    at public java.lang.Throwable[] sacredData.jaxws.IOExceptionBean.suppressed
    at sacredData.jaxws.IOExceptionBean

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:106)
at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
... 58 more
```

Comment: How exactly do you create your `JAXBContext`? Seems like you're creating it for something like `IOExceptionBean` which holds a `Throwable` which is not compatible with JAXB. The thrown exception has nothing to do with this.
In short, please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using webservices, you can use URL class loader to load files. It is good to store the files in Resources folder of your project. Following is the code snippet I used to get a mapping file from the Resources folder of my project

```
 URL resource = YourClassName.class.getResource(filePath);
    File file = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
```

You can get the input stream from that **file** and load your properties.

Comment: Thank you @venkat for helping me out. But im not sure how to make the properties file outside project environment. and I was new to web services. therefore i dont quite know how to do that.